# Why do we take array of size one more than the size of queue in Circular Queue?

Tags: queue, size

Why do we take array of size one more than the size of queue in Circular Queue since it seems to work even without the +1.

Comment: A little more context would be helpful for this question.  What are you storing in the queue?  What operations are you performing on the queue?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-circular-queue this reference to circular queues does not require any of the representations to be larger than the content size.

Comment: @PeteB I'm storing numbers in the queue. I'm performing Enqueue and dequeue. I'm in a learning stage. This question was asked in my finals. Thanks.

Comment: I suspect that you have misremembered the question or it refers to some particular optimisation that your lecturer uses but which is not commonly applied.  I have now done a moderately extensive Google search on circular queue and circular buffer implementations, and cannot find a single one that requires a larger array then the size of the queue! (One really good ref: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UxHY8D-1fJY) Sorry I couldn't help more.